# How can I calculate the value of $\sin(\pi^2)$ if the expression in Euler's for involves a denominator with $i$?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I understand that $$\sin(\pi^2)=\frac{e^{i\pi^2}-e^{-i\pi^2}}{2i}$$ but how can we then evaluate this to get a real number solution if it has a denominator with $i$?

Comment: Simpler question: why is $i/i$ a real number if it has a denominator with $i$?

Comment: Let use Taylor series for both exponent. $e^{\pm i \pi^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\pm i)^n \pi^{2n}}{n!}$. When $n=2k$: $i^n=(-i)^n$ then terms compensate each other. At $n=4k+1$, $(i)^n-(-i)^n=2i$, at $n=4k+3$ $(i)^n-(i)^{-n}=-2i$. Then $\sin \pi^2=\frac{1}{2i} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{2i (-1)^m \pi ^{2(2m+1)}}{(2m+1)!}$, $\sin \pi^2=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m \pi ^{2(2m+1)}}{(2m+1)!}$, which is the same expression as result of using sin Taylor series applied to $\pi^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice you have a complex number of the top as well, not just on the bottom. So the RHS is a ratio of 2 complex numbers, which certainly can be real.

One way to convince yourself of this is to notice that the numerator must be imaginary, otherwise the ratio is not real. To then convince yourself that the numerator *is* in fact imaginary, note that
$$
e^{ix}
 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(ix)^n}{n!}
 = x^0 + ix - \frac{x^2}{2!} -i\frac{x^3}{3!} \pm \ldots
$$
and the pattern repeats every 4 terms with coefficients $1, i, -1, -i$ in front of the standard exponent Maclaurin series. For $-i$, everything stays the same but the coefficient pattern changes from $1, i, -1, -i$ to $1, -i, -1, i$, getting
$$
e^{-ix}
 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-ix)^n}{n!}
 = x^0 - ix - \frac{x^2}{2!} +i\frac{x^3}{3!} \pm \ldots
$$
It's easy to notice that the even-power terms have no $i$ and are the same, and odd-power terms have the $i$ with opposite signs. So the you subtract the second equation from the first, even-power terms cancel out and off power terms have an extra factor of $2i$ in front of the usual exponent Maclaurin series:
$$
\begin{split}
e^{ix} - e^{-ix}
 &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(i^n-(-i)^n\right)\frac{x^n}{n!} \\
 &= 2ix - 2i\frac{x^3}{3!} \pm \ldots \\
 &= 2i\left(x - \frac{x^3}{3!} \pm \ldots \right) \\
 &= 2i \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} \\
 &= 2i\sin(x)
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. I now have a follow up question - how does a calculator perform the calculation $\frac{e^{i\pi^2}-e^{-i\pi^2}}{2i} = -0.4303...$?

Comment: It doesn't. When calculating the sine of a real number, a calculator would use a formula that doesn't involve any imaginary component, such as just using the Taylor series $x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\ldots$.

Answer (score 1):

*For the fun of the calculation of $\sin(\pi^2)$ as a function of $\pi$*

$$\sin(\pi^2)=\sin(3\pi-\pi^2)$$ Using the Taylor series
$$\sin(x)= \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1} $$ Use $x=3\pi-\pi^2$ and compute the partial sums
$$S_p=\sum^{p}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} \big[3\pi-\pi^2\big]^{2n+1}$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & S_p \\
 0 & \color{blue}{-0.4}44826440320 \\
 1 & \color{blue}{-0.430}156764030 \\
 2 & \color{blue}{-0.430301}898884 \\
 3 & \color{blue}{-0.43030121}5124 \\
 4 & \color{blue}{-0.43030121700}3 \\
 5 & \color{blue}{-0.430301217000}
\end{array}
\right)$$